# SQL array[], FK, PK

Tags: sql, массивы, база-данных

Две таблицы между собой соединены через PK и FK, но во второй таблице FK имеет массив [].

Как мне создать запись другого формата?

Пример кода:

```
create table tab1 (tab1_id serial primary key, timez TIME, name
varchar(15));

insert into tab1 (tab1_id,timez,name) values
(3,'05:15:05','pavel2121$@PO');

create table tab2 (tab2_id serial primary key, last varchar(10), tab1
VARCHAR(10)[], foreign key (tab1) references tab1 (tab1_id));
```

Detail: Столбцы ключа "tab1" и "tab1_id" имеют несовместимые типы: character varying[] и integer.

Но если я уберу массив и изменю формат на int, код работает, но невозможно добавить необходимую мне информацию.

Comment: На будущее: "новичок" пишется через "о".

Comment: и то верно, спасибо.

Comment: если у вас столбец во второй таблице ссылается как вешний ключ на первую, то типы данных у ни должны быть одинаковы. Что за информацию вы хотите добавить?

Comment: to teran, хочу записать буквы и цифры, но т.к. tab1_id имеет int и он PK, а данные в tab2 ссылающиеся по FK + ещё array [] который должен отображаться в этой строчке или это просто невозможно?

Comment: Давайте лучше не абстрактными table1-table2 оперировать, а каким-то конкретным примером, что было понятно о чем речь. Сейчас ясно, что вам надо сохранить какую-то дополнительную информацию. Сохранять ее можно либо в этой же таблице в доп. столбце, либо в какой-то доп.таблице. Очевидно, в столбец ключа пихать ничего не надо.